# What are power cube transformers?

Tags: transformer, device, electric-machine

If I'm not wrong, is the term "Power cube transformers" is less commonly used to refer "A.C/D.C Adapter"? I couldn't find the use to this term.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a strictly defined technical term, that's a slang term (*power brick* is also widely used to mean the same) meaning any box that plugs into the outlet and gives output useful for powering electronics. It can be a power supply (usually a switching one) or a charger (often based on a switching power supply) - anything that looks more or less like a cube and giving out power.

Comment: another term for this item: wall wart.

Comment: I've heard of "power brick" and "wall wart", but not "power cube transformer".  As with all these terms, it's best not to use them unless you are really sure they will be understood correctly in the context you are using them.

Comment: "power cube transformer" makes me think of the transformers that have a cable from the wall to the "block" and then another cable from the block to the device. This is like what most laptops have. Where as wall wart is the ones that the block pretty much sits on the outlet itself.